# Фоновая картинка

Tags: css

Народ, подскажите как вставить фоновую картинку определенной высоты так, чтоб она не уменьшалась по ширине? Когда пытаюсь вставить, то фоновая картинка стала как-бы увеличенного размера (такое чувство что её приблизили)

```
header { 
  background-image: url(image/bg-header.png); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  height: 753px; 
}
```

Comment: А вы понимаете, что у вас написано? В частности `background-size`

Comment: Хороший вопрос. У меня тот же. Как сделать адаптивный задний фон из картинки для div.

Comment: А как правильно прописать?

Comment: Для этого нужно понять что же вы хотите получить.

Comment: Я хочу чтоб картинка была определенной высоты, но при этом не масштабировалась по ширине

Comment: Т.е. что бы она меняла пропорции?

Comment: Я не знаю как объяснить, на данный момент я вставил фоновую картинку в блок, задал этому блоку высоту, фоновая картинка вставилась, всё нормально, но её как-будто приблизили

Comment: @user237042 это из-за background-size: cover; - удалите это свойство

Comment: Удалил это свойство, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: вот пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/nf3zfaho/

Comment: У вас на той картинке, которая нижняя, не отображается трава внизу, картинка так же как-будто увеличенная не много

Comment: добавил еще 3 вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/nf3zfaho/2/

Comment: А можно код только на последний вариант?

Comment: @user237042 обновил